# Output a string if a given element does not exist in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mysql

<strike>I have an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that needs to either output the value of a specific element if that element exists, or output the string "NULL" if it doesn't. How can I accomplish this?</strike>

### Update

The document I'm working with looks something like this:

```
<kanjidic2>
    <header>
        <file_version>4</file_version>
        <database_version>2010-325</database_version>
        <date_of_creation>2010-11-20</date_of_creation>
    </header>
    <character>
        <literal>亜</literal>
        <codepoint>
            <cp_value cp_type="ucs">4e9c</cp_value>
            <cp_value cp_type="jis208">16-01</cp_value>
        </codepoint>
    </character>
    <character>
        <literal></literal>
        <codepoint>
            <cp_value cp_type="ucs">226F3</cp_value>
            <cp_value cp_type="jis213">2-12-48</cp_value>
        </codepoint>
    </character>
    <!-- Plus a few thousand more <character>s -->
</kanjidic2>
```

I'm writing an XSLT stylesheet to transform the above into a series of MySQL queries. Initially I wanted to output NULL if the character did not have a jis208 codepoint associated with it (hence my initial question), producing a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `kanji` (`literal`, `ucs`, `jis208`, ...) VALUES ('亜', '4e9c', '16-01', ...);
INSERT INTO `kanji` (`literal`, `ucs`, `jis208`, ...) VALUES (', '226F3', NULL, ...);
```

I've since realised that I could make the XSLT simpler and produce a shorter query instead:

```
INSERT INTO `kanji` (`literal`, `ucs`, `jis208`, ...) VALUES ('亜', '4e9c', '16-01', ...);
INSERT INTO `kanji` (`literal`, `ucs`, `jis213`, ...) VALUES ('', '226F3', '2-12-48', ...);
```

### The solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <template match="/">
        <apply-templates select="kanjidic2/character"/>
    </template>

    <template match="/kanjidic2/character">
        <text>INSERT INTO `kanji` (`literal`</text>
        <apply-templates select="codepoint/cp_value" mode="first"/>
        <text>) VALUES ('</text>
        <value-of select="literal"/>
        <apply-templates select="codepoint/cp_value" mode="second"/>
        <text>);&#10;</text>
    </template>

    <template match="/kanjidic2/character/codepoint/cp_value" mode="first">
        <text>, `</text>
        <value-of select="@cp_type"/>
        <text>`</text>
    </template>
    <template match="/kanjidic2/character/codepoint/cp_value" mode="second">
        <text>, '</text>
        <value-of select="."/>
        <text>'</text>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

I will mark Dimitre Novatchev's answer as the correct one because it is the most succinct solution to my *initial* question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short solution that doesn't use at all XSLT conditional processing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:param name="pDefault">NULL</xsl:param>
 <xsl:variable name="vDefault" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pDefault']"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat(//myelement[@myattribute='avalue'],
              $vDefault[not($vDoc/*/myelement[@myattribute='avalue'])]
              )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<mydoc>
    <myelement myattribute="avalue">Some text</myelement>
    <myelement myattribute="anothervalue">Some more text</myelement>
</mydoc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Some text
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<mydoc>
    <myelement myattribute="anothervalue">Some more text</myelement>
</mydoc>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
NULL
```

**Do note**:

No conditional instruction (`<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>`/`<xsl:when>`/`<xsl:otherwise>`) is used at all.

Comment: Since you posted this, I've thought of a better way to achieve what I want to do. But since you perfectly answered my initial question, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will only ever be zero or one matches in a given document, but that they could be at any location within that document, the following will probably do what you're after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//myelement[@myattribute = 'avalue']"><xsl:value-of select="//myelement[@myattribute = 'avalue']"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>NULL</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If they're always going to be in a specific point in the document, you can make the above more efficient by changing the "//" in the path to "myelement" to the proper path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx) with [`xsl:if`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp) to output different values:

```
<xsl:if test="count(myelement[@myattribute = 'avalue']) = 0">
NULL
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="count(myelement[@myattribute = 'avalue']) &gt; 0">
  <xsl:value-of select="myelement" />
</xsl:if>
```